# Run imageJ in batch

Tags: linux, batch-file, imagej

I have downloaded `imageJ` for `Linux`,

but I am unable to run it with the batch flag (`-batch`).

The  [instructions](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/install/linux.html)    here:

say that `imageJ` is ran using `./run`, and can be run with a script with -`batch` scriptPath.

But running *./run -batch*  does not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you type ./run you execute a shell script containing the line

```
./jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -jar ij.jar
```

Try typing on the command line

```
./jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -jar ij.jar -batch <your_args>
```

from the imageJ directory.